# How filter json file with jq using bash

Tags: json, bash, jq

I am trying to filter my json file using bash, which file could be something like:

```
{
    "key1": [],
    "key2":["first_value","second_value"]
}
```

In case I would like to fetch key1 and key2 I got I can do something like:

```
if $(cat $my_json | jq 'has("key1")'); then
  values=$(jq -r ".key1" "$my_json")

  for item in $values
  do
    echo "Item : $item"
  done
fi
```

The output of the previous is:

```
Output:

Item : []
```

This prevents any issues in the case my file hasn't such key and I want to verify that.

How can I verify that values is empty, referred to my example?
I want to avoid any iteration on empty values.
Is there any way to verify the existing key with jq, that should not be empty?

The goal I would like to achieve is something like **redirected at the end of a file**

```
key2:
- first_value
- second_value
```

in case of key, since it is empty I don't want to have any results

Comment: You can check, output and iterate all within jq. What is the ultimate goal of your `for` loop?

Comment: I need to iterate all values in case my key is not empty and do some operation on that values

Comment: You can output the numeric length of the array using `length`. But chances are you can also do "some operation on that values" within jq.

Comment: how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jq you can use the `length` filter to get the size of an array.

```sh
$ echo '{"key1": [], "key2":["1","2"]}' | jq -r ".key2 | length"
2
$ echo '{"key1": [], "key2":["1","2"]}' | jq -r ".key1 | length"
0
```

Also, even with that you'll find a problem iterating the elements of the array stored in `$values`. I think that what you want is this:

```sh
values=$(jq -r ".key1[]" "$my_json")
```

Comment: Is there any way to use your suggestion passing a variable instead of key1?

something like jq --arg key "$KEY" .$key[] myfile.json?

Comment: Bash variable expansion happens **before** the call to `jq`, so you can even: `key=your_key; jq ".${key}[]" myfile.json`

Comment: thank you! unfortunately for some reason when I perform that the script crashes going in segmentation fault! I am really confused

paths_list=$(cat $CONFIGURATION_FILE | jq -a -r “.path[]“)
echo $? <---- 139

Comment: [root@800a5f2d17f5 /]# jq -a -r ".path[]" myconffile.json 
"*/mypath"
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[root@800a5f2d17f5 /]#

Comment: I think that -a is the cause of my crash

Answer (score 2):

One option might be using

```
jq '.| select( has("key1"))|to_entries[] | select( .value | length == 0 )' $my_json
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/go9Uy3DV73)</kbd>

Edit(*after question's edit*): If you need to get the values of the non-empty arrays unlike to the previous one, then just convert the above filter to

```
jq -r '.......| length > 0) | "\(.key):", "- \(.value[])"' $my_json
```

through use of string interpolation

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/HZsgfwVxdD)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

This discards all items with an empty array, and iterates over the rest printing out the key name, then all array items.

```sh
jq -r 'to_entries[] | select(.value | length > 0) | .key, "- \(.value[])"'
```

```
key2
- first_value
- second_value
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/k86OLyNnsz)